# Binomial Probability to find N? Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

A doctor thinks that, when treated with a new drug, a patient has a probability of $\frac25$ to
improve. How many patients must he treat to be sure (at $p >.95$) that at least one
patient will improve?

Comment: What have you tried? Any thoughts on what distribution is appropriate?  Are the patient results independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- If the probability a patient will improve is $p$ then the probability a patient will not improve is $q=1-p$
- If the patients' improvements are independent then the probability none of $n$ of them will improve is $q^n$
- What probability values do you want for this event?

Set up the inequality and solve, possibly using logarithms and rounding.